# Include a snippet with raw content in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need a way to so something like this.

```
{% raw %}
  {% include "snippet" %}
{% endraw %}
```

Except this prevents include from running. So it doesn't do what I need.

Ideally there was a `include_raw` tag.

**Update:**

The following:

```
<!-- reggi 090 -->

<script type="text/liquid">
  {% capture raw_data %}{% include 'product_thumbnail' %}{% endcapture %}
  {% raw %}{{ raw_data }}{% endraw %}
</script>
```

Simply renders to:

```
<!-- reggi 090 -->

<script type="text/liquid">

  {{ raw_data }}
</script>
```

Comment: You would have to put the `{% raw %}` tag inside the included file in order for that to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{% capture raw_data %}{% include 'snippet' %}{% endcapture %}

{% raw %}}{{ raw_data }}{% endraw %}
```

Comment: The `capture` tags will only get the liquid output from the include. It's not gonna return unparsed / raw liquid. I do not think this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: No. `capture` will convert whatever `include` returns into a string. And since you want the returned string not to be parsed into HTML you can pass it through `{% raw %}`

Comment: Added the example above. Just renders the literal `{{ raw_data }}` because it's what is in between the raw statement.

Comment: Interesting. I have just gone through my theme file where the developer implemented this featurette using JS. I presumed he was using `raw`, my bad. Usage: `<script id="some_unique_id" type="text/template">{% include 'xyz' %}</script>` - supposedly stores the entire html in `xyz` snippet as an un-rendered string.

Comment: So assuming your `product_thumbnail` returns a `<div>..</div>` it is stored entirely as a string. Later on, calling the script with the id returns the entire thing - `$('#some_unique_id').text`